# Rails doesn't load my images' assets in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a problem with my Rails application in production on Elastic Beanstalk. 
Everything's fine in local, but when I deployed, all my pictures are not found (404). I put all images in app/assets/images.

I've tried to change the config.serve_static_files in my config/environments/production.rb, but neither true or false does work.

I'm using the ruby stack with Passenger. Single instance.

Platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.0 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)

Thanks for your help !

julian

Comment: What version of Rails are you running?  Are you using the Asset Pipeline?  If so, are you certain you have committed your generated assets to your repository before deploying to production?

Comment: I'm running Ruby 2.2 (local and production). I just checked and I don't have any generated files in the public folder. The weird thing is that I have 2 other rails app with the same structure and I don't have this problem. Here is an image call example from my homepage : <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="" />

Comment: oh ok ! I need to commit those files

Comment: How to debug this:  pick a single image.  Look in chrome inspector, or the equivalent in whatever browser you use, at an img like or the style or whatever has the path to the missing image.  Is that image on your server, relative to your app's public folder?  Or, if the url is an aws url, then is that file there?  Is it in a bucket which is set to private?

Comment: My images are relative to the rails instance. Let's use logo.png for example. The file is here : app/assets/images/logo.png. When I try to call this image directly from my browser with http://server/assets/logo.png, I get a 404 with the rails error page (The page you were looking for doesn't exist). And in my logs, I have a RoutingError, no route matches...

Comment: So I changed all my assets' calls to use the pipeline and it works. I don't understand when the other method works or not. Anyway ! Thank you guys !

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same problem just the other day. I was referencing a .jpg file in my css for background-image but it was giving me a 404.

```
  background-image: url('background2.jpg'); //worked locally but not on AWS EB
```

When checking the code in the dev terminal I noticed that it was in fact requesting "/assets/background2.jpg" but I think that when Rails serves images in the asset folder it usually renames them with a long string after the file name (e.g. "/assets/background2-b438af190a4.........jpg")

In my case, using asset_path helped. Note: since I used it in css I had to change the file extension to scss.

```
  background-image: url(asset_path("background2.jpg")); // .scss file
```